# How to use a connection string from web.config in a OleDbConnection control from the designer?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, designer, oledbconnection, oledbcommand

My app makes use of OleDbConnection and OleDbCommand objects for executing queries.  These are controls you can just drag and drop onto the designer.  I can set the connection string on the OleDbConnection just fine from within the designer.  The problem arises when I remove the connection string from the OleDbConnection and put it in my web/app .config.  When I open/view the queries in the OleDbCommand objects, it throws this error:

```
"The ConnectionString property has not been initialized"
```

I have an OracleConnection object that doesn't throw this error but will pop up a box asking for connection string info.  I don't want that either.

Before I moved the connection strings to my web.config, I was able to open the queries up in the designer (by clicking the ellipses next to the query), and even execute it if I wanted.

***How can I get the designer to use the connection string inside my web.config so it stops throwing the above error when I try to open the queries from the designer?***

I will note that the app works at run time because I'm setting the connection string from within the constructor of the code behind file using the ConfigurationManager.

Comment: Have you tried this: `<%=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Name"].ConnectionString%>`

Comment: This isn't an ASP.Net MVC app so I'm not using razor syntax.  I tried putting the above from within the designer and it just through an invalid syntax error.  I think it only takes string literals is the problem.  FYI, this is a WCF service - not that that matters.